# Disable title / author in the HTML output of bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

In Bookdown, if you provide the title and the author of your book in `index.Rmd` like so:

```
--- 
title: "My New Book"
author: "John Doe"
(...)
---
```

It uses this information to generate a nice (and common) first page in the PDF output, with the title centered, and the author's name below that.

But in the HTML output, the title and the author's name is just put there at the top of the index page.

[image: example HTML output]

As I've seen on [www.bookdown.org](https://bookdown.org/), the HTML version of most books start with this text, and then display the cover image of the book right after that anyway. (Like [the book above](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/) or [this one](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/).) I think if the cover image was at the top here, it would look much better.

Can the title / author part be **disabled** for HTML output?

I haven't found an example where it was removed, so I'm not sure if this is possible. I've tried removing it from `index.Rmd`, but then it is removed from the PDF too, which I don't want.

(I use the Bootstrap style.)

Answer (score 6):

I've found a **workaround** for this.

Add a `css` property to `bookdown::html_book` in `_output.yml`:

```
bookdown::html_book:
  (...)
  css: style.css
```

In this file (`style.css`), add:

```
.author,.title{
    display: none;
}
```

This will apply this CSS to the output HTML. Although it will still contain the title and author lines, but they won't be displayed.